# ListViewItem's group not being preserved through another collection

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-3.5

I'm trying to implement a search function in a custom `ListView` and as such I am hiding `Items` with a custom `ObservableCollection` which allows `AddRange`, similar to the [one defined on damonpayne.com](http://www.damonpayne.com/post/2010/03/04/AddRange-for-ObservableCollection-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) (for the tl;dr-ers out there basically it suppresses firing `OnCollectionChanged` event while adding multiple items then fires with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`):

```
public new MyCollection<ListViewItem> Items { get; protected set; }
```

The `MyCollection_CollectionChanged()` populates `base.Items`:

```
this.BeginUpdate();
base.Items.Clear();
base.Items.AddRange(this.Items.ToArray());
this.EndUpdate();
```

The idea is that when items do not fulfill the search terms, they are removed from `base.Items` (i.e. *System.Windows.Forms.ListView*) but remain in `this.Items` (i.e. *My.Name.Space.MyListView*). When the search is cancelled or the terms change, `base.Items` can be repopulated by `this.Items`.

This works fine and as expected except for one small but important caveat:

The problem is that `ListViewItem`s' `Group` is not consistently being carried from `this.Items` to `base.Items` and as such all the items appear in the group "Default".

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

### Update

I'm still stuck on this. Surely doing the `.ToArray()` just creates a shallow copy of the `Items` so the `Group` should be preserved?
This has been confirmed by [Maverik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504757/maverik):

> [I just called in Linqpad, and while the list reference is different, you're right.. object references are same](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5751203#5751203).

### Update 2

Okay after some more investigating I've found where it is happening.

When adding `ListViewItem`s to the `MyCollection<ListViewItem>`:

```
var item0 = new ListViewItem();
var item0.Group = this.Groups["foo"];
//here this.Items.Count = 0
this.Items.Add(item0); 
//here this.Items.Count = 1 with item0 having group "foo"

var item1 = new ListViewItem();
var item1.Group = this.Groups["bar"];
//here this.Items.Count = 1 with item0 having group "foo"
this.Items.Add(item1);
//here this.Items.Count = 2 with item0 having group "null" and item1 having group "bar"
```

I also checked this replacing `MyCollection<` with the normal `ObservableCollection<` and the same still occurs.

### Update 3 - Solution

Please [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476858/listviewitems-group-not-being-preserved-through-another-collection/12862649#12862649).

Comment: ahah, +1 for the tl;dr-ers part

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Background

Figured it out!

I don't know why but an exception wasn't being thrown when it should have been.

The exception `Cannot add or insert the item 'item0' in more than one place.` should have been thrown.

(After clearing out some stuff from a `.designer.cs`, it was thrown (though curiously not when stepped through...)

As requested the code cleared from the designer of the form containing the custom `ListView` was

```
this.ListView.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
    listViewItem1,
    listViewItem2,
    listViewItem3,
    listViewItem4,
    listViewItem5,
    listViewItem6});
```

These were just some temporary items which I had added previously for test but the designer must have remembered them for some reason.)

---

### The Solution

The solution is as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6582142/1185053) and my code now reads:

```
this.BeginUpdate();
base.Items.Clear();
base.Items.AddRange(this.Items.Select((ListViewItem)a => a.Clone()).ToArray());
this.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Could you please mention those stuffs which you removed in order to get your problem rectified.. it may help others if it really solved the problem..